# iOS Swift UICollectionView Layout Attributes for Cell With Indexpath Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I am having UICollection View in my app. My app getting crash With error:
`UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000023916> {length = 2, path = 569 - 0}`. How to fix it?

Note: 
   I am having this problem only for iPhone5/iPhone5s

Code Here:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
  return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return self.RecentlyUsed.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    if(self.RecentlyUsed.count > 0)
    {
        let nameString = ((self.RecentlyUsed[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String)
        let textfield = UITextField()  //PT Serif Caption 19.0
        textfield.text = nameString
        var  myTextViewSize = CGSize()
        myTextViewSize = textfield.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textfield.frame.width,height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        return CGSize(width: myTextViewSize.width + 10,height: 50)
    }
    return CGSize(width: 0,height: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CSNewsRecentlyUsedCustomCell
   cell.ButtonAction.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
   cell.ButtonAction .addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonselected), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
   cell.ButtonAction.setTitle("\((self.RecentlyUsed[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String)", for: UIControlState.normal)
   return cell
}
```

Comment: I think you are making scroll to collectionview for perticular indexpath which is not there

Comment: @Swift_Guru In iPhone 5s `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` not yet call

Comment: can you put your code where you are getting this error?

Comment: @Swift_Guru When I am opening that storyboard app getting crash. I did CollectionView delegate and datasource correctly.

Comment: @Swift_Guru But same thing works perfectly in other phone. I am having problem only with iPhone5s

Comment: but atleast show your code

Comment: @Swift_Guru Above post updated with code

Comment: ok but you said you are getting crash while you enter in that screen so i think there is no issue with collectionView methods, the issue will be in where you reload collectionview or scroll collectionview in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method

Comment: @Swift_Guru How to fix it?

Comment: are you getting any warning?

Comment: @Swift_Guru I have Check my code end. When I am trying from my iPhone 6s CollectionView method is calling. But in iPhone5s CollectionView method won't call

Comment: @Swift_Guru no I am not getting any warning

Comment: are you using collectionView.scrollToItem(at:indexPath) method ?

Comment: @Swift_Guru no. but I'm using `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: can you show me that code?

Comment: @Swift_Guru already in above code `collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize`

Comment: Compare (dupe?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038695/uicollectionview-cellforitem-called-not-correctly check isn't it prefetch enabled?

Comment: @Swift_Guru yes Prefetch is Enable. I have unchecked it and try but also I'm getting same error